# How to evaluate improper integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x} dx$?

It can not be represented in terms of elementary functions.

$\lim_{x \to 0} {\frac {\sin(x^3)}{x}} = 0$ and integral converges.

Help me, please!

Thanks!

Comment: Why not write the original integral as $\int \frac{x^2\sin(x^3)}{x^3} \;dx$ then let $u=x^3$ to get the integral in the form $\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{\sin u}{u} \;du$.

Comment: You can use series to evaluate.

Comment: I do replacement $t = x^3$ and get $\frac {1}{3} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac {sin(t)}{t} dt$ and etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the original integral as 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2\sin(x^3)}{x^3} \;dx$$
 then let $u=x^3$ to get the integral in the form 
$$\frac{1}{3} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u} \;du$$
it is well known that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \; dx=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
giving us the answer
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x^3}{x}\;dx=\frac{\pi}{6}
$$

Comment: To obtain the middle integral, there are many methods (mostly using complex analysis that I am familiar with), see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral